# terminate the coroutine and start the new one if already running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

building Unity3D programme with C# I am completely new to Unity and C#.

Here is the code,

```
void Update() {
    //do something with bool unit and eventually it gets to true
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {
        if (coRunning == true) {
            StopCoroutine ("Coroutine");
            coRunning = false;
        }
        StartCoroutine ("Coroutine");
    }
}

public IEnumerator Coroutine() {
    coRunning = true;
    while (!unit) {
        yield return null;
    }
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().transform.Rotate (0, 90, 0);
    coRunning = false;
}
```

When 'A' is pressed, it should wait until bool 'unit' is true before rotating the body 90 degree. If unit does not get to true before another 'A' is pressed, the origianl Coroutine should be stopped and the new one should start.

However, when I press 'A' two times, the body rotates 180 degree at once when unit turns true. Any help with this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: all the 2nd if after the keypress does is stopping the coroutine. it should instantly work as soon as you put StartCoroutine in the 2nd ifs else. if its not running start it, if its running stop it. think it through line by line, write down the values of the variables if needs to.

Comment: @thanks for help, but you may have misunderstood my question. But it is solved now, I may have not saved the script after change!